# MySQL IF statement in Trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I just want to create trigger in my sql but some error happened

this is the code

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_santri_in_kamar
AFTER UPDATE ON
santri
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE stat INT
SET stat = select status FROM santri WHERE id_santri=new.id_santri

IF (stat = 0) THEN
DELETE FROM santri_kamar_asrama WHERE id_santri=new.id_santri
END IF

END
```

and this is the error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET stat = select status FROM santri WHERE id_santri=new.id_santri

IF (stat =' at line 7
```

please help me

Comment: Your statements need terminators (;) - and if you trying to create trigger in mysql  did you set the delimiter to something other than ; before trying to create the trigger (and reset it after)?

Comment: You are missing the semicolons after each statement within the body of the trigger. Also, the whole body could be replaced by a single multi-table update statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Add semicolons after the statements** and **change default delimiter(`;`)** before the code of create trigger. Otherwise it will give

```
SQL Error(1064): You have an error in your SQL Syntax;
```

After the create trigger code make `;`  as default delimiter

```
   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER delete_santri_in_kamar
    AFTER UPDATE ON
    santri
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE stat INT;
    SET stat = (select status FROM santri WHERE id_santri=new.id_santri);

    IF (stat = 0) THEN
    DELETE FROM santri_kamar_asrama WHERE id_santri=new.id_santri;
    END IF;

    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I still get same error message and for each row with semicolon has extra error message that said "Unexpected character near (;)"

Comment: im sorry but it still doesnt working, anyway thanks for your help bro.

Comment: What is the error now. I got it working in my phpmyadmin